# "up and down to play"

Tags: grammar, idioms

Does the following sound natural to native speaker?

*"Message me when players are up and down to play".*

Where "to be up" is awake, and "to be down to play" is eager/willing to play.

In case it sounds off, how would you change it?

Comment: Why not put the meanings in directly, i.e. _Message me when players are awake and eager to play_?

Comment: I actually like the way the sentence works - there's a pleasurable double-take in parsing it.

Comment: A different one-word change you might want to consider: replace *down* with *ready*. Sounds just right.

Comment: In my usage, “down” is less about being immediately ready to go and more about being interested, willing, and expressing commitment”-  By saying you’re  down you are figuratively putting your name down on the list for doing it.  But players could be “down” for play the night before.  So unless expect the person you’re messaging to wake the players up and then try to convince them they should play and to message you when they’re convinced and have agreed,  you probably want something more like “ready” as @RichardKayser says.

Comment: @Jim Good comment. I'm not as hip as you are, as I was unaware of this sense of 
*down*. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "Message me when players are up and down to play".

I would add a comma to signal a small break. In actual speech this would be reflected as a rising tone on the word "up". If the tone is level, we get the impression that *up-and-down* is a unit.

*Message me when players are up, and down to play*

Answer (score 0):

It sounds correct in the context, but I would add both a comma before the coordinating conjunction and a helping verb to "down" to lessen the ambiguity.

> "Message me when players are up, and **are** down to play".

Answer (score -2):

Assuming the slang definition for the word "down" is known, the sentence sounds correct. A comma does not appear to be necessary because you are only listing two qualities. As an American English speaker, this sounds normal to me because I use the word "down" for its slang meaning often.

If you wanted to change it so the distinction between the two qualities is more clear, then you could say:

Message me when players get/wake up and are down to play.

It is not necessary to change it though.